# How do I convert a String that looks like an int to the correct format?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a String variable that looks like this.
`String milli = "2728462"` is there a way to convert it to look something like this
`2,252,251` which I guess I want as a long.

The thing is it will be passing strings in this format
`1512`
`52`
`15010`
`1622274628`

and I want it to place the `,` character where it needs, so if the number is `1000` then place it like so `1,000` and `100000` then `100,000` etc.

How do I properly convert a String variable like that?

Because this

```
String s="9990449935";  
long l=Long.parseLong(s);  
System.out.println(l);
```

Will output `9990449935` and not `9,990,449,935`

Comment: `long` and `int` _never_ have any formatting.  Only `String`s have formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Basic strategy for is to convert string representation of the number to the one of `Number` format. Then you have following options to represent this number according to the give `Locale`.

#### String.format()

```
System.out.format(Locale.US, "%,d", Long.parseLong("2728462"));
```

#### NumberFormat

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(Long.parseLong("2728462")));
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! :-)

Comment: @MarkDenom - The relevant knowledge is - you should convert the String to some kind of Number, then use the normal number formatting methods to get the output you want. Good answer oleg, but I think more explanation will help future readers.

Comment: By the way, System.out.format() is a synonym of the perhaps more familiar System.out.printf().  String.format() can be used instead of System.out.format() if you want the output to be written to a string instead of printed.

Comment: This is definitely correct answer, I upvoted it. @Mark Denom you should accept it as the best answer. Just to add something related: method parseLong() throws NumberFormatException if the String isn't valid long. I wrote an Open source library that has a utility that converts Strings to Long, Integer, Float etc that doesn't throw the exception but, if exception occurred it returns a default value and optionally prints the exception into a log. This may be convinient. See the article about the lib: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
String milli = "2728462"
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(Long.parseLong(milli)));
```